# Name of the matrix that appears in matrix form of Hamilton's equations of motion

Tags: terminology, hamiltonian-formalism

Consider a harmonic oscillator described by the second order differential equation
$$\ddot{\phi} + \omega_0^2 \phi = 0 \, .$$
Defining $v \equiv \dot \phi$ we get two simultaneous equations
\begin{align}
  \dot \phi &= v \\
  \dot v &= - \omega_0^2 \phi \, .
\end{align}
Rescaling the variables to $X \equiv \phi$ and $Y \equiv v / \omega_0$, we get
\begin{align}
  \dot X &= \omega_0 Y \\
  \dot Y &= - \omega_0 X
\end{align}
which can be seen as coming from the Hamiltonian
$$H = \omega_0 \left( \frac{X^2}{2} + \frac{Y^2}{2} \right)\, .$$
Writing the equations of motion in matrix form gives
$$\frac{d}{dt}
  \left(
    \begin{array}{c} X \\ Y \end{array}
  \right) = \omega_0 \left(
    \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array}
  \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} X \\ Y \end{array} \right) \, .
$$

Is there a standard name for that matrix?
In other words, is there a general name for the matrix that appears when expressing Hamilton's equations of motion in matrix form?

Comment: That's the *symplectic metric* in phase space.  See these pages : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry.

Comment: @Cham I am asking for a term that refers to the matrix that falls into that position in the first order differential equations. In this particular case, it is the symplectic matrix, but that's only because I chose coordinates to make it so. I'm looking for the name of the matrix that fills that position in general, e.g. even in the case where I have two *coupled* resonators and the matrix is 4x4 and not symplectic.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could be thought of $i \sigma_2$ where $\sigma_i$ are the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

Alternatively, this is the most simple linear [complex structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and it's [standard symplectic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space). The study of symplectic vector spaces and symplectic manifolds grew out of the study of Hamilton's equations in classical mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia:Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

> The matrix
>   R = $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$
>   rotates points in the $xy$-plane counterclockwise through
>   an angle $\theta$ about the origin of a two-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system.

So your matrix $ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
is the special case of that for the rotating angle $\theta = -90°$.